# Property changing value but not updating the UI

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This question seems to come back a lot but i don't find any answer that can solve my problem.

Yes i have NotifyPropertyChanged implemented and it works all around my app.

But for this i am trying to change the visibility of my stacklayout if an ImageButton is clicked, if i look at the debuger, the value changes but visually it's not changing.

The ImageButton is still there but the value in the debuger is equal to false.

There must be something that i don't get about binding, if someone could help out, it would be nice.

Thanks.

**The second ImageButton is binded to the DeleteIconPressed Command which will fire the change of IsVisible of the stacklayout in the second code snipet.**

```
        <CollectionView.Header>
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="220">
                    <Label Text="Agenda" TextColor="Black" FontSize="18"/>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">


                    <ImageButton Source="iconplus.png"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Clicked="GoToNewTaskPage"></ImageButton>
                    <ImageButton Source="iconmoins.png"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Command="{Binding DeleteIconPressed}"></ImageButton>
                    

                </StackLayout>


            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>

    </CollectionView.Header>
```

**Further in the code i have this stacklayout which i binded to a boolean property  to change the visibility**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="DeleteIcon" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6" IsVisible="{Binding DeleteIsPressed}">
<ImageButton Source="iconmoins.png" HeightRequest="25" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TasksGroupCollection}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteTasksGroupCommand }" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="#00FBC1BC"></ImageButton>
</StackLayout>
```

**In my viewmodel which inherit from BaseViewModel that has the Notify interface implemented ( which works for everything that i did in my app), i have the boolean and the command implemented.**

```
private bool deleteIsPressed;
public bool DeleteIsPressed
{
    get
    {
        return deleteIsPressed;
    }
    set
    {
        deleteIsPressed = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DeleteIsPressed");
    }
}

    public Command DeleteIconPressed { get; set; }

    public TasksGroupPageViewModel()
    {


        DeleteIconPressed = new Command( () => DeleteIconPress());


        GetTaskgroups();


    }

    private void DeleteIconPress()
    {
        DeleteIsPressed = false;

    }
```

Comment: is `DeleteIcon` part of your CollectionView ItemTemplate?

Comment: Yes everything is wrapped in a CollectionView which refere to x:Name="TasksGroupCollection" which might be why it doesn't work but i am unsure on how to approach this problem when this is the case ? Thanks.

Comment: so if the delete button in the header is pressed, you want the Delete ImageButton in every row to be hidden?

Comment: The was just for me to check fast if it was working but what i really want to do is initialize the false by default and when the delete button in the header is pressed, i want the delete ImageButton in every row to be shown ( true).

Comment: just use the same syntax in the IsVisible binding that you do in the Command binding

Comment: I had the solution right in my face i feel bad haha thanks a lot, while were here, do you have an idea on how i could switch it back to false when clicked again in my command ? Thanks !

Comment: `DeleteIsPressed = !DeleteIsPressed;`